# GLSL convert valid glm::mat4 matrix to nan matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, opengl-3

I follow tutorial http://www.mbsoftworks.sk/tutorials/opengl3/ and try to compile 10th example.

Everything work fine besides place I send (projection matrix mul modelview matrix) to the shader.

There is place where I send matrix:

```
//...
// render.cpp
    glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = *(oglControl->getProjectionMatrix());
    glm::mat4 cam = glm::translate(mModelView, cCamera.vEye);
    auto newM = projectionMatrix * cam;
    spDirectionalLight.setUniform("projectionMatrixMulModelViewMatrix",&newM);
//...
```

```
//...
// setUniform implementation
void CShaderProgram::setUniform(string sName, glm::mat4* mMatrices, int iCount)
{
    int iLoc = glGetUniformLocation(uiProgram, sName.c_str());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(iLoc, iCount, FALSE, (GLfloat*)mMatrices);
}
//...
```

and at the end mMatrices contain
[image: [mMatrix content]] .

Shader code

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrixMulModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 inNormal;

out vec2 texCoord;

smooth out vec3 vNormal;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrixMulModelViewMatrix*vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    texCoord = inCoord;
    vec4 vRes = normalMatrix*vec4(inNormal, 0.0);
    vNormal = vRes.xyz;
}
```

The result is blank screen. Renderdoc debugger tells me that gl_position matrix completely NaN.
[Renderdoc screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NUjc.png)

When I send glm::mat4(1) I got valid result.

Why after multiplication shader got NaN vector?

Comment: You have to initialize `mModelView = glm::mat4(1.0f)`

Comment: Actually, mModelView is inicialized before. It's not the reason.
`glm::mat4 mModelView = cCamera.look();`
`
`glm::mat4 CFlyingCamera::look()
{
 return glm::lookAt(vEye, vView, vUp);
}`

Comment: As I mention before mMatrix is **VALID**

you can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0DOk.png)

Comment: @Rabbid76: Doesn't seem to be a duplicate as the glm matrix is ok. The problem is probably the upload to the shader.

Comment: @DiliDup: Do you call `glUseProgram` before `setUniform`? What is the value of `iLoc`? Why does the call to `setUniform` not contain a third parameter

Answer (score 0):

Seems like VS2017 tricked me. I haven't initialize matrix deep inside code:

```
glm::mat4 mModelView = cCamera.look();
```

```
glm::mat4 CFlyingCamera::look()
{   
    glm::mat4 result = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    result = glm::lookAt(vEye, vView, vUp);
    return result;
}
```

and here is my fault

```
void CFlyingCamera::update()
{
    // Change camera view direction
    rotateWithMouse();

    // Get view direction
    glm::vec3 vMove = vView-vEye;
    vMove = glm::normalize(vMove);
    vMove *= fSpeed;

    // Get normal to view direction vector 
    glm::vec3 vStrafe = glm::cross(vView-vEye, vUp);
    vStrafe = glm::normalize(vStrafe);
    vStrafe *= fSpeed;

    int iMove = 0;
////
////
///// ERROR HERE, vMoveBy isn't initialized
    glm::vec3 vMoveBy;
///// 
////
////    
// Get vector of move
    if(Keys::key(iForw))vMoveBy += vMove*appMain.sof(1.0f);
    if(Keys::key(iBack))vMoveBy -= vMove*appMain.sof(1.0f);
    if(Keys::key(iLeft))vMoveBy -= vStrafe*appMain.sof(1.0f);
    if(Keys::key(iRight))vMoveBy += vStrafe*appMain.sof(1.0f);
    vEye += vMoveBy; vView += vMoveBy;
}
```

But debugger gave me valid matrix anyway. Do you know why it's happened?